# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver On Android

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

Today I am doing Connectivity of `SqlServer` using `JTDS` driver. But when I run program
I found Below error

```
Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.kmkm.lll-2.apk]
```

I already search on this topic and I found answer as

```
java -classpath .:jtds.jar MyApp
```

but I am confuse how and where I run this command? 
Why this error comes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Android app in Eclipse. What worked for me was to export the external jars with my app.

If you have already added the jtds-1.2.5 driver, good. Otherwise:

Right click on the Project > Properties > **Libraries** Tab
Add the jtds-1.2.5.jar file by clicking on "Add External JARs"

Next, in the **Order and Export** tab (Right next to **Libraries** in the Java Build Path window) check the box for *jtds-1.2.5.jar* (and any other external jars you might have).

This will export the .jar containing the driver with the .apk file.

Comment: There seems to be an issue when using 1.3.0 drivers. This is how I found this answer which didn't work. I then downgraded to 1.2.7 and putting it in the libs directory everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a third party library, make sure you have all its required dependencies, if it requires any.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, Try this steps

- Right click on your project
- Click Build Path > Configure Build Path...
- Choose Libraries tag and click Add External JARs...
- Point your jtds.jar and click OK.
- Rebuild and run again.