# Android - classnotfound on using jdbc connecting to MSSQL

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to make an android application that reads data from `MSSQL` Server 2008. I've found out [an example](http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/) about using `JDBC`, but it's not working for me.

I've followed answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295264/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-net-sourceforge-jtds-jdbc-driver-on-android) from Roger Garza, but the class is still not found

I cannot import images to post, but i have jtds-1.3.0.jar just under Android Dependencies.

My code is:

```
public void query2()
{
Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
Connection conn = null;
try {
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYIPSERVER:1433/SERVERNAME;encrypt=false;user=sa;password=password;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
String username = "sa";
String password = "password";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
Log.w("Connection","open");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select TOP 10 * from MyTable ORDER BY Transac DESC");

//Print the data to the console
while(reset.next()){
Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
//&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
}
conn.close();

} catch (Exception e)
{
Log.w("Error connection","");
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The error is right after this line - `Class.forName(driver).newInstance();` - cause i've commented the code after and i have the same error log.
The logcat is:

```
11-21 16:05:55.480: I/Android(1679):  MySQL Connect Example.
11-21 16:05:55.499: W/System.err(1679): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
11-21 16:05:55.499: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at com.example.holz1.MainActivity.query2(MainActivity.java:46)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at com.example.holz1.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 16:05:55.509: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 16:05:55.519: W/System.err(1679):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
11-21 16:05:55.519: W/System.err(1679):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-21 16:05:55.519: W/System.err(1679):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
11-21 16:05:55.529: W/System.err(1679):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-21 16:05:55.529: W/System.err(1679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-21 16:05:55.543: W/System.err(1679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 16:05:55.543: W/System.err(1679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-21 16:05:55.543: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 16:05:55.549: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 16:05:55.549: W/System.err(1679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-21 16:05:55.549: W/System.err(1679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-21 16:05:55.549: W/System.err(1679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 16:05:55.599: W/System.err(1679): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver
11-21 16:05:55.599: W/System.err(1679):     ... 19 more
11-21 16:05:55.610: W/System.err(1679): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
11-21 16:05:55.619: W/System.err(1679):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-21 16:05:55.619: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-21 16:05:55.629: W/System.err(1679):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-21 16:05:55.629: W/System.err(1679):     ... 19 more
11-21 16:06:51.519: W/WindowManager(90): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
11-21 16:06:51.552: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(90): setKernelCountSet(10013, 1) failed with errno -2
11-21 16:06:52.499: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(90): setKernelCountSet(10047, 0) failed with errno -2
```

Comment: I would recommend a REST API from your server to provide the data instead of direct connection. Always bear in mind that on mobile, you might lost connection on a regular basis. Open DB connections might be a serious issue over time...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused due to jar, please download **sqljdbc-1.2.0.jar** and place it in lib folder in root directory

[download sqljdbc-1.2.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc120jar.htm)

Comment: Yes, I found the same thing happening on v1.3.0. I used 1.2.7 and every worked as expected. Who's fault it really is I'm not sure...