# How to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver Error?

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, jtds

I am new to Android and I am trying to connect Android Studio with Microsoft Sql Server using jtds-1.3.1. but I can't able to connect as it shows me the following error

`E/java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`

I tried all the possible ways as from Google from youtube but still i cant able to solve it. Hope I can find a solution here

Comment: FYI, SQL Server isn't SSMS. SSMS stands for SQL Server Management Studio; which is an IDE for SQL Server.

Comment: Before you get too invested in this approach please consider the following: do you really want to put your SQL Server on the public internet so that mobile devices (and all and sundry) can access it directly? Almost always you want to put some kind of web API in front of your SQL Server and have your applications use that instead. This also helps to decouple from SQL Server so that you can move to or mix in other technologies on the backend.

Comment: See also previous SO question/answer, [Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295264/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-net-sourceforge-jtds-jdbc-driver-on-android).